# grunt.registerTask can not modify global grunt task settings

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

The following code reads the contents of every subdirectory `js` inside of `app/modules/` (eg. app/modules/module1/js/, app/modules/module2/js/, aso.)

this script worked before WITHOUT using the last command `grunt.task.run('concat:' + dir);`.
for a while now it stopped working so that i had to add a call to the task concat inside of the forEach loop.

normally I would have saved the new configuration inside of the concat configuration and call sometime later the resulting concat task.

```
grunt.registerTask('preparemodulejs', 'iterates over all module directories and compiles modules js files', function() {

    // read all subdirectories from your modules folder
    grunt.file.expand('./app/modules/*').forEach(function(dir){

        // get the current concat config
        var concat = grunt.config.get('concat') || {};

        // set the config for this modulename-directory
        concat[dir] = {
            src: [dir + '/js/*.js', '!' + dir + '/js/compiled.js'],
            dest: dir + '/js/compiled.js'
        };

        // save the new concat config
        grunt.config.set('concat', concat); 
        grunt.task.run('concat:' + dir); // this line is new

    });

});
```

what exactly changed in recent versions that i have to add an explicit task.run line?

and is there any way to write the settings of this task into the settings of an existing concat task so that if i have other manual additions to that configuration those won't run for each directory scanned?

thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

`grunt.task.run();` despite it's name, does not run tasks. Grunt is always synchronous so `grunt.task.run()` will **queue** tasks to run after the current task has finished.

So I would avoid using `grunt.task.run()` within an array but rather build a list of tasks/targets to run afterward:

```
grunt.registerTask('preparemodulejs', 'iterates over all module directories and compiles modules js files', function() {
  var tasks = [];

  // read all subdirectories from your modules folder
  grunt.file.expand('./app/modules/*').forEach(function(dir){

    // get the current concat config
    var concat = grunt.config.get('concat') || {};

    // set the config for this modulename-directory
    concat[dir] = {
      src: [dir + '/js/*.js', '!' + dir + '/js/compiled.js'],
      dest: dir + '/js/compiled.js'
    };

    // save the new concat config
    grunt.config.set('concat', concat); 
    tasks.push('concat:' + dir);
  });

  // queues the tasks and run when this current task is done
  grunt.task.run(tasks);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also provide a config directly here for different tasks to run on the go for bigger projects having multiple modules. Even if the we need to process files outside of the root directory:

```
grunt.registerTask('publishapp', 'uglify ivapp.js and upload to server', function (){
    var tasks = [];
    grunt.file.expand('../outerdirectory/').forEach(function(dir) {
        // config for uglify that needs to execute before uploading on server
        var uglify = {
            options: {
                compress: {
                    drop_console: true,
                },
                banner: '/* Banner you want to put above js minified code. */\n'
            },
            all: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '../',
                    src: ['somedir/some.js'],
                    dest: 'build',
                    ext: '.js',
                    extDot: 'last'
                }]
            }
        };
        // set grunt config : uglify 
        grunt.config.set('uglify', uglify);
    });
    // prepare a tasks list
    tasks.push('uglify:all');
    tasks.push('exec:publish');

    // execute a tasks to perform
    grunt.task.run(tasks);
});
```